# Moving celery to a remote, dedicated machine for a Django project

Tags: django, celery, remote-server

I run asynchronous tasks via celery for a social networking Django web application of mine. In my current setup, celery workers and celerybeat are run on the web application server, whereas a postgresql DB resides on a separate server.

Asynchronous tasks ought not impede/slowdown user experience, thus I've decided to move them to their own dedicated machine (they've now become quite voluminous).

My question is regarding how to achieve the aforementioned architecture. The asynchronous workers are manipulating tables and rows in the DB.

1) How would I call my asynch workers in a remote location,

2) How would I route their results to effect the required changes in the DB?

Would love to know the most efficient way to achieve this, and an illustrative example would be nice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to change the `BROKER_URL`like this:

BROKER_URL = 'amqp://username:password@myremotehost.com//'

So first you have to decide what broker you want to use, more information can be found here http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/index.html.

In the above example of `BROKER_URL`, I have mentioned to use rabbitmq-server.

On your remote server you have to put your code(may be using git or svn), then you need to install whatever broker you decided to use, in my example case, you have to install `rabbitmq-server`. In ubuntu you can type:
     `sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server` to install `rabbitmq-server`

Then you need to install `celery` like this:
    `pip install celery`

You may further user `supervisor` to manage you celery to start, restart and stop. More information about `supervisor` can be found here: http://supervisord.org/

**Edit 1:**

Answer 1: Celery function calling is same.

Answer 2: you have to just add the remote machine db host in settings.py file like this:

I am assuming that you use `MySQL` as database.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': your_db_name,
        'USER': your_db_user,
        'PASSWORD': your_db_password,
        'HOST': your_remote_db_host_here,
        'PORT': your_port_no_for_mysql_here,
    },
}
```

So what this setting will do is that it will tell all user(user like celery) of you application to connect to the remote host for the MySQL database.

Comment: @HassanBaig See my Edit 1

Comment: @HassanBaig Read my answer very carefully. I have mentioned this thing in my answer's 5th paragraph. You have to clone your project on celery server as well

Comment: Well, according to the 5th paragraph, it seems I'll need to pull *my entire project* from git/svn on the remote server? So it seems my remote server will be a snapshot of my web application server, except it'll have celery workers and will not handle traffic like the web app server does, hence no need to install nginx or fire up gunicorn either. That's the case?

Comment: Yes, entire project needs to be cloned to make life easy and no need to fireup nginx and gunicorn. Btw nginx and gunicorn are not part of project